# Regarding pyspark conversion

Tags: python, pyspark

I need a help to convert this pandas dataframe to pyspark dataframe

```py
df=df.groupby('col', as_index=False).agg({'col' : 'first', 'country' : ', '.join})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you just try?

```
pandasDF = pysparkDF.toPandas()
```

Answer (score 0):

using `toPandas()` is taking lot of time. Is there any way to rewrite the below snippet into pyspark?

```
df=df.groupby('col', as_index=False).agg({'col' : 'first', 'country' : ', '.join})
```

Appreciate your help.